# python path finding question using data structures and algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, path-finding

I am in a intermediate comp sci data structures and Algorithms class and for part of my homework, I was assigned this question.

"You are given a spool of string and some wooden balls to which the string can be attached. Briefly
describe in words/pictures how you could solve the problem of finding the shortest path between two
vertices. Also solve the shortest path to all other vertices."

could someone help explain and visualize how to execute this problem?